# USB to DVI adapter not recognized in 17.10

Tags: drivers, usb, multiple-monitors, dvi

I have a StarTech USB32DVIEH USB to DVI adapter that I have connected to my HP all-in-one PC running Ubuntu 17.10.

I checked StarTech.com for Ubuntu drivers and there were none for this particular device. I then downloaded and installed the DisplayLink drivers and even after rebooting, the monitor I have connected is still dark.

Any and all input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This adapter uses the MCT Trigger Family chipset, and not DisplayLink. There appear to be no compatible drivers for Linux, and it is a patented proprietary device. It will not currently work under any Linux, including Ubuntu.

Comment: Bummer :( Guess I'll just have to deal with what I have until someone figures out a fix. I simply don't have the time or knowledge to do it myself :(

Comment: The "fix" is to return it and buy a different adapter that is based on DisplayLink, or to reverse engineer drivers to make it work. I wouldn't expect the latter to happen anytime soon.